# how i can filter model's field that is similar to inputted value?

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

im new in django . in my homework user will input a data (string) in template and i must filtering field with this data. but the problem is inputted data its just "similar" with field's value. so i can't use `MyModel.objects.filter(name__contains=value)` . 
i found documentation that a solution will be using `MyModel.objects.filter(name__trigram_similar= value)` but this queryset needed to install `'django.contrib.postgres'` and i  haven't permission to change "setting.py" part so unfortunately i can't use this solution .
for more information you should know filed's value and inputted value will be at least 75% similar to each other and the length of them will be exactly equal.

here is some models filed's value and inputted value :

```
filed's value:      inputted value:
spring                spting
 john                  jfhn
 hello                 pello
 love django         llve djabgi
   .                     .
   .                     .
   .                     .
```

its just like Typographical mistakes.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess you will have to write your own "similarity" method and filter manually.

Comment: thanks @Selcuk for response. that will be last solution.  i will trying to found lazy solution first  :)

Comment: try out this package https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/. Also if you have the password you can change the file permission witg 'sudo chmod 666 <filename>'

Comment: @marke exactly what i want . thank you